# Prevent submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to prevent the submission of data when user enters a number or a special character. I've used this.

```
//restric entering numbers and special characters

function checkLetters() {
    var crop = $('#crop').val().trim();

    //Entering numbers 
    if (crop.match(/([0-9])/)) {
        $('#cropEr4').show();
        boolsub = false;

    }
    else {
        $('#cropEr4').hide();
        boolsub = true;

    }

    //Entering special characters
    if (crop.match(/([!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) {
        $('#cropEr3').show();
        boolsub = false;

    }
    else {
        $('#cropEr3').hide();
        boolsub = true;

    }

}
//prevent submitting
function validateSubmit() {
    var crop = $('#crop').val().trim();
    if (crop !== "") {
        $('#cropEr2').hide();
        if (boolsub) {
            boolsub = false;
            return false;
        }
        if (boolsub) {
            boolsub = true;
            return true;
        }
    }
    else {
        $('#cropEr2').show();
        return false;
    }

}
```

below is the form.

```
   <form name="myForm" action="../controller/new.php" method="POST" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validateSubmit()">
    <table align="left" width="300" height="200">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Crop Name : </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="crop_id" value=""size="45" id="crop" onkeyup="checkLetters(this.value);"/>
                <div id="cropEr2" style="display:none;color:red">Enter crop name</div>
                <div id="cropEr3" style="display:none;color:red">You cannot enter symbols, have to enter only letters.</div>
                <div id="cropEr4" style="display:none;color:red">You cannot enter numbers, have to enter only letters.</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <input class="button"type="reset" value="Clear Deatils" />
            </td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_crop" />
                <input class="button" id="submit"  type="submit" value="Add Details" />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work? When I enter numbers and special characters the message is displayed, but it is submitting the form anyway. 
I'm loading this code in a facebox.

Comment: It looks like `boolsub` needs to be in the outermost scope.

Comment: If using jQuery, don't use the onclick/onsubmit attributes. Connect the events using jQuery. It allows for multiple handlers and is easier to maintain the code.

Comment: Look in your JavaScript error console. What does it say? (Note you might have to configure it to allow messages to persist since the form is being submitted and loading a new page).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Done your code with preventing special characters and blank fields. just try to implement like this way...

**HTML :**

```
<form name="myForm" action="../controller/new.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validateSubmit()">
<input type="text" name="crop_id" value=""size="45" id="crop" />
<input class="button" id="submit"  type="submit" value="Add Details" />
<div id="message" style="color:red;"></div>
</form>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//prevent submitting
function validateSubmit(){
    var crop = $('#crop');
    var sh = $('#message');
    if(bv(crop,sh) === true && sc(crop,sh) === true){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
function bv(e,sh){
    var a = e.val().trim();
    //Entering blank characters
    if (a == ""){
        sh.html('Blank not allowed.');
        return false;
    }else{
        sh.html('');return true;
    }
}
function sc(e,sh){
    var b = e.val().trim();
    //Entering special characters
    if (b.match(/([0-9,!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)){
         sh.html('Allows only characters.');
         return false;
    }else{
        sh.html('');return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This obviously works for you, just try to implement.

Comment: I did another validation , but the error message is displaying in the top of the form, instead of displaying it below the input field. What may be the wrong ? any suggestion @Rocky . This happens only in one form.

Comment: yes, you can put message div everywhere in your html and also you can put div message out of <form> tag then and then it also works.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to not rely on JavaScript when there are saner options available.

Compare your wall of code, to this:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" required />
```

Suddenly it only allows letters, and even won't submit until you type something!

Isn't HTML5 awesome?

Comment: If the world only used HTML5 this would be a reasonable answer to the problem. JQuery is all about still working on the rest of the world's machines too :)

Comment: It's about time we stopped pandering to people using ancient web browsers. Client side validation is only a convenience to the user, it becomes less reasonable to invest time in writing large chucks of JS for features that are native in HTML to provide that convenience to a shrinking minority.

Answer (score 0):

First you test to see if the string contains any numbers. If it does, you set `boolsub` to `false` otherwise you set it to `true`.

Then you test to see if it contains any special characters. If it does, you set `boolsub` to `false` otherwise you set it to `true`.

It doesn't matter what value you set `boolsub` to for the number test. You always overwrite that value for the special character test.

Set `boolsub` to `true` by default. Set it to `false` if it fails a check. Never reset it to `true` if it passes a check.

```
function checkLetters() {
    boolsub = true;
    var crop = $('#crop').val().trim();

    //Entering numbers 
    if (crop.match(/([0-9])/)) {
        $('#cropEr4').show();
        boolsub = false;
    } else {
        $('#cropEr4').hide();
    }

    //Entering special characters
    if (crop.match(/([!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) {
        $('#cropEr3').show();
        boolsub = false;
    } else {
        $('#cropEr3').hide();
    }

}
```

Note, however, that you would be better off rewriting this so that `checkLetters` returned a value instead of setting a global, and to use [modern event binding techniques](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Comment: @huz — Yes, it does! (In combination with the rest of the original code)

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE AFTER OP's COMMENT**

```
var boolsub = true;
function checkLetters() {
    var crop = $('#crop').val().trim();
    if ((crop.match(/([0-9])/)) || (crop.match(/([!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/))) {
        $('#cropEr3').show();
        boolsub = false;
    }
    else {
        $('#cropEr3').hide();
        boolsub = true;
    }

}
//prevent submitting
function validateSubmit() {
    var chek = 0;
    var crop = $('#crop').val().trim();
    if (crop !== "") {
        $('#cropEr2').hide();
        if (boolsub) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        $('#cropEr2').show();
        return false;
    }
}

<form id="form1" runat="server" action="abc.html">
<table align="left" width="300" height="200">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Crop Name : </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="crop_id" value=""size="45" id="crop" onkeyup="checkLetters(this.value);"/>
                <div id="cropEr2" style="display:none;color:red">Enter crop name</div>
                <div id="cropEr3" style="display:none;color:red">You cannot enter symbols or numbers, have to enter only letters.</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <input class="button"type="reset" value="Clear Deatils" />
            </td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_crop" />
                <input class="button" id="submit"  type="submit" value="Add Details" onclick="return validateSubmit()" />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eLy600wt/2/)**

Comment: Are you just trying to make it possible to bypass the client side validation by submitting the form by pressing enter in a text input?

Comment: Some browsers will trigger the click event on a submit button if the form is submitted by other means. I wouldn't want to depend on it, and it is a much less elegant solution to the problem. The original code [works](http://jsbin.com/lufofuzadoba/1/) anyway, so your change certainly doesn't fix a problem.

Comment: @Quentin: It doesn't work. Check your code of `paste bin`. Enter some numbers, press Submit and it won't for first time but again press submit button with same values and it will submit.

Comment: @Quentin yup,i want to prevent client entering numbers and special characters and submitting the form. and in the original code [link](http://jsbin.com/lufofuzadoba/1/) , when u enter a number and click once it is not submitting but when it click again, it is submit.

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi — Ah. I'd missed that part of the question and was just testing against an empty string. Actual solution identified now.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is " event.preventDefault()" : : If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

And add an event for submit button.

```
$( "#submit" ).click(function( event ) {
   var crop = $('#crop').val().trim();
            if (crop !== "") {
                $('#cropEr2').hide();
                if (boolsub) {
                    boolsub = false;
                    event.preventDefault()
                }
                if (boolsub) {
                    boolsub = true;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else {
                $('#cropEr2').show();
                event.preventDefault()
            }

});
```

You can remove this line: **onSubmit="return validateSubmit()"**

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=L2vRaIkMNT

[image]

Comment: There's no `event` object in `validateSubmit`. It's using old style intrinsic event attributes, so the return value is used to determine if the default behaviour is triggered.

Comment: See my post. You should add a validation on click.. .You will have event object.

Comment: @codebased it is not working even after adding 'event' as u suggest in ur answer .